# Uploading Image to symfony 3 from form

Tags: symfony, web

I am trying to make a sell item page. The form and page render
I'm not entirely sure what I am doing wrong, but when I hit the submit I get an error 500. There might be a syntax error that I am not catching

I have the parameter set as image_directory: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/images'

```
class SellPage extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/SellItem", name="Sell_Item")
         */
        public function goToSellPage(Request $request)
        {
            $item = new Item();

            $sellForm = $this->createFormBuilder($item)
                ->setMethod("POST")
                ->add('name', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Item Name: ', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control form-group')))
                ->add('price', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Price: ', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control form-group')))
                ->add('image', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Image Upload Click Here', 'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-lg form-group')))
                ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array('label' => 'Description', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control form-group')))
                ->add('category', EntityType::class, array('class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Category', 'choice_label' => 'name', 'label' => 'Category', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control form-group')))
                ->add('seller', EntityType::class, array('class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User', 'choice_label' => 'userName', 'label' => 'Seller', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control form-group')))
                ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit', 'attr' => array( 'class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-success form-group')))
                ->getForm();

            $sellForm->handleRequest($request);
            if ($sellForm->isValid())
            {
                $formData = $request->request->get('sellForm');
                $item->setName($formData['name']);
                $item->setPrice($formData['price']);
                $item->setDescription($formData['description']);
                $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:User');
                $item->setSeller($repository->getUserByName($item->getSeller()));
                $item->setBuyer($repository->find(2));

                $fileName = 'http://sfsuse.com/~sp17g01/sp17g01/web/images/'.md5(uniqid()).$sellForm['image']->getData()->guessExtension();

                $sellForm['image']->getData()->move(
                    $this->getParameter('image_directory'),
                    $fileName);





                $item->setImage($fileName);



                $catRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Category');
                $item->setCategory($catRepository->find(1));

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($item);
                $em->flush();



            }

            return $this->render('default/SellItem.html.twig',['sellForm' => $sellForm->createView(),]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you check the logs to see what is causing the 500 error?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://dancostinel.com/blog/web/blog/how-to-create-upload-functionality-using-symfony3) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

In you parameters.yml file use:

```
image_directory: images
```

And I also think you need to change `$filename` like so:

```
$fileName = 'images/'.md5(uniqid()).$sellForm['image']->getData()->guessExtension();
```

If you are getting errors, it's best to append `app_dev.php` to your symfony app URL (debug URL). So for example on localhost use:

http://localhost/app_dev.php

And then point to route by appending the route, example:

http://localhost/app_dev.php/myRoute

Then you will get more debug info. I suggestion using the deubg URL for development use.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this construction:

```
       if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $img = $user->getImg();
                if ($img !== null) {
                    $img = $user->getImg();
                    $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$img->getExtension();
                    $img->move(
                        $this->getParameter('user_images'),
                        $fileName
                    );
                    $user->setImg($fileName);
                }
            }
       }
```